# sequelize.synch returns Got error 168 from storage engine

Tags: mysql, node.js, linux, sequelize.js

I got a nodeJS application with a MySQL DB on a Linux (Ubunut 16.04 LTS). I'm running on localhost. I'm using **sequelize (3.23.0)** to do DB manipulation (create, update, etc.)

I got an error message when the following code gets executed (file is called "`initSequelize.js`"):

```
db
.sequelize
.sync({alter:true})
.finally(function(err){
  if (err) {
    console.log("init sequelize error");
    throw err[0];
  } else {
    console.log("foo sequelize");
  }
})
.catch(function(error){
  console.log("uh oh in Sequelize: ", error);
});
```

The error message:

> foo sequelize
>
> uh oh in Sequelize:  {SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_GET_ERRNO: Got error 168 from storage engine
>
> //...
>
> code: 'ER_GET_ERRNO',
>
> errno: 1030,
>
> sqlState: 'HY000',
>
> index: 0,

As you can see, it goes into the else clause and then throws that error. But in the else clause is nothing that could cause an error. Also, I got the permission to write in the mysql folder.

At first I thought I'm running short of storage. Therefore I deleted not needed files. I got over 100 GB of free storage place. But the error still shows.

Further below I would see this error message:

> From previous event:
>       at Promise.then (/home/path/to/project/node_modules/sequelize/lib/promise.js:21:17)
>       at Sequelize.sync (/home/path/to/project/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:995:6)
>       at database (/home/path/to/project/init/initSequelize.js:11:6)

Line 11 is referring to "`.sync`" in the code above

I also deleted my whole project and cloned the project again, deleted the whole MySQL database and re-created an empty one (basically start from scratch). Yet the error still persists (and it used to work before).

**EDIT:**
I ran `df -h`

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

udev            3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev

tmpfs           794M   20M  775M   3% /run

/dev/sda1       222G  113G   98G  54% /

tmpfs           3,9G  236M  3,7G   6% /dev/shm

tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock

tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup

cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs

tmpfs           794M   68K  794M   1% /run/user/1000

/dev/sdc1       7,3G  2,6G  4,8G  36% /media/fooBarUser/2256-3EDA

The mysql data directory is `/var/lib/mysql` as stated in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d`

Comment: Check to make sure the database storage is on the partition with all that free space :)

Comment: It would also be helpful to run `df -h` and post it here. Usually mysql lives on the root partition by default, mainly `/var/lib/mysql` which could be a small partition.

Comment: @MiiinimalLogic please see my update

Comment: I see, so you're at about 54% usage on the root partition. Where is the mysql data directory?  check the `/etc/my.cnf` file for the data directory.

Comment: @MiiinimalLogic I went to the folder (on the GUI) then right clicked on the mysql folder. It says Free storage place: 105.1 GB. Therefore I assume in that folder I got 105.1 GB of free storage available.

Comment: @MiiinimalLogic The mysql is in /var/lib folder. Are you sure it is ".cnf" or is it ".conf"? I checked the folder /etc but couldn't find a file called "my.cnf". I can't find a file called "my.conf" either. :/

Comment: @MiiinimalLogic so I went to `etc/mysql` and found a file called my.cnf. The content is:

    !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/`

    !includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/`

Comment: Check for files in that dir then. If you read MySQL's docs you'll see you can have configuration files in multiple places and some locations will override others. Once you find that file, you're looking for the `datadir` directive and its value.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/44280212/491553