# ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 168 from storage engine

Tags: mysql, create-table, data-recovery

Had a drive crash and recovered my mysql databases from backup.  One table didn't make it and I deleted it and its associated files. (InnoDB table.)  The table name was "filescan" and there are now no files in the data directory with that root name.

I am able to create and delete other table names, but not "filescan".  When I try that, I get an error.

```
mysql> create table deleteme (id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)

mysql> create table filescan(id int);
ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 168 from storage engine
mysql> drop table deleteme
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> drop table filescan;
ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'db1.filescan'
mysql> create table filescan(id int);
ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 168 from storage engine
mysql>
```

Other answers on Stack Exchange and elsewhere seem to indicate this happens when there's a shortage of disk space. I have 130GB+ free and am able to create other tables - just not one named "filescan".  I thought it might be a permissions issue, so I checked the permissions of the other files and the enclosing /data folder to ensure I have access.

Any insights?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/44280212/491553